# How to pre-allocate a 3 dimensional array in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory-management, multidimensional-array

In matlab, how do you pre-allocate a 3 dimensional array with zeros if my dimensions are 10 rows, 5 columns, and 45 entries in the third dimension.

Part of my problem is that I'm trying to keep track of the temperature changes of certain points on a 2 dimensional grid over time. Basically I have a 2-D grid of 10 x 5 points in space and i want to track each point's temperature change over time. I'm having trouble pre allocating this 3-D array with all zeros.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `zeros` function.

```
myarray = zeros(10, 5, 45)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the function `zeros()`

```
M=zeros(10,5,45)
```